# R data.frame columns into single list

Tags: r

I can't seem to find answer though I'm sure it's already been asked...but I wanted to extract and combine a subset of data.frame columns into a single list without use of any packages. For example:

```
DF <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6), c = c(7,8,9))
test <- c(DF[,1], DF[,2], DF[,3]) # Gives what I want
test <- c(DF[,1:3]) # Doesn't give what I want
```

So desired output would be a single list of values 1:9. 
I'd want the subset to be dynamically assigned so I can't do it the way I typed it even though it is giving the output I'd like. The only other way I could think is to have a loop and incrementally add one column at a time e.g. test <- c(test, DF[,i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `unlist`:

```
unlist(DF)

# a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

And to get rid of names if needed:

```
unlist(DF, use.names = FALSE) # or also unname(unlist(DF))

# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `c` within `do.call`

```
test <- do.call(c,DF)
```

such that

```
> test
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `flatten` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
DF %>%
   flatten_dbl
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```